# Pop to navigate back view to pass data in which way better?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controls. 
First view control to move second view controller and pass the data.
My question is I have pop to first view control and pass the data, in two way of set delegate methods and set notification observe to pass data and manage my action activity.
In both way in what way is better for pass secure data?
Plz. explain in details.

Comment: You can also pass in a closure or do an unwind segue, whichever way is better just depends on your needs, there's no one formulae to tell you what method you should use to pass back data

Comment: both way are useful and also good think for applied, but how to it use and applied base on your code logic and type of action activity performing on your app activity.

Comment: Notification is basically u call to every observe instance in your app to execute, its not a good way to pass data, its just good to execute something based on event, so use delegate or block

Answer (score 0):

if one value pass to one viewcontroller i think block it better ，because block you can write less code。
notification is bad，delegate is good，many framwork use block pass value usually like AFNetworking，
but one value past to more than two controller at one time notification is best ，this my own idea。

Answer (score 0):

1) Unwind segue

2) protocol & delegate

3) block (If you know it better    than use it first)

4) Notification & Observer

Follow it in sequence manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way creates your delegate methods., for your given two options to choose in one for my own suggestion. Because then you are using Notification observer to define and remove it., but you are using Delegate method for pass various types of data (as you defined) and called the delegate method for managing your action activities.

I am not saying a using delegate is the best way, but all way is best based on your coding logic and your developing system workflow and performing action activity.